# Python, pandas: summing a column based on multiple other columns and putting it into a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

I have this data set that I have been able to organise to the best of my abilities.  I`m stuck on the next step. Here is a picture of the df:

[image]

My goal is to organise it in a way so that I have the columns `month`, `genres`, and `time_watched_hours`.

If I do the following:

`df = df.groupby(['month']).sum().reset_index()`

It only sums down the 1`s in the genre columns, whereas I need to add each instance of that genre occurring with the `time_watched_hours`.  For example, in the first row, it would add 4.84 hours for genre comedies.  In the third row, 0.84 hours for genre_Crime, and so on.

Once that`s organised, I will use the following to get it in the format I need:

`df_cleaned = df.melt(id_vars='month',value_name='time_watched_hours',var_name='Genres').rename(columns=str.title)`

Any advice on how to tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: Looking at this further, it would also work to replace the "1" in each row with the `time_watched_hours` value, then I can `groupby().sum()` down.  Note there may be more than one value of "1" per row.

Comment: post data, not pics. also include your expecred output

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding and using `mask` for each column which worked perfectly. Downside was I had to list it for each column

```
df['genre_Action & Adventure'].mask(df['genre_Action & Adventure'] == 1, df['time_watched_hours'], inplace=True)
```